# How to wait for file to close in batch file than proceed for execution

Tags: batch-file

I have following batch script which opens a file and wait for process to close than read from the file

```
@ECHO OFF

call file.txt
:wait
tasklist /M notepad++.exe > nul && goto wait
FOR /F %%i IN (file.txt) DO @echo %%i
PAUSE
```

but it is stuck at the loop itself can someone please suggest what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try

```
call file.txt

:wait
tasklist /fi "imagename eq notepad++.exe" |findstr "notepad++.exe"
if "%errorlevel%"=="0" goto wait
FOR /F %%i IN (file.txt) DO @echo %%i
PAUSE
```